# Memory error in Python script for PostgreSQL queries

Tags: python, postgresql, out-of-memory

My Python script for updating a PostgreSQL database table column is being interrupted by a memory error. The script reads data from an XML file `Posts` which is about 28 GB and attempts to update column `parentid` in database `forum`.

An example of what the error looks like is below:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "dbUpdate.py", line 43, in <module>
>     update_table('C:\\dataset\\Posts')
>   File "dbUpdate.py", line 23, in update_table
>     for event, elem in iterparse(xml_file):
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1304, in __next__
>     self._parser.feed(data)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1235, in feed
>     self._parser.feed(data)
> ```

And what follows is the Python script:

```
import psycopg2
import gc
import sys
import os
from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse
import logging

def update_table(file, 
    dump_path='C:\\dataset', 
    update_query='UPDATE posts SET parentid={parentIdValue} WHERE id={idValue};', log_filename='parser.log'):

    logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(dump_path, log_filename),level=logging.INFO)

    with open(os.path.join(dump_path, file + '.xml'), encoding='utf8') as xml_file:
        table_name = file
        cur = conn.cursor()    

        for event, elem in iterparse(xml_file):                
            if elem.tag == "row":
                logging.debug(elem.attrib.keys())

                if 'ParentId' not in elem.attrib.keys() or 'Id' not in elem.attrib.keys():
                    continue

                parentIdVal = elem.attrib.get('ParentId')
                idVal = elem.attrib.get('Id')

                query = update_query.format(parentIdValue=parentIdVal,idValue=idVal)
                cur.execute(query)
                conn.commit()

            elem.clear()
        conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="forum", user="postgres", password="password", port="5432")
    print ("Opened database successfully")
    update_table('C:\\dataset\\Posts')
    conn.close()
```

There's definitely something I'm missing as far as memory handling in Python. Would appreciate any pointers.

A snippet of my xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="4" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="7" CreationDate="2008-07-31T21:42:52.667" Score="305" ViewCount="20324" Body="&lt;p&gt;I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;This is my code:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;&#xA;this.Opacity = trans;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;When I try to build it, I get this error:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;blockquote&gt;&#xA;  &lt;p&gt;Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I tried making &lt;code&gt;trans&lt;/code&gt; a &lt;code&gt;double&lt;/code&gt;, but then the control doesn't work. This code has worked fine for me in VB.NET in the past. &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="8" LastEditorUserId="451518" LastEditorDisplayName="Rich B" LastEditDate="2014-07-28T10:02:50.557" LastActivityDate="2014-07-28T10:02:50.557" Title="When setting a form's opacity should I use a decimal or double?" Tags="&lt;c#&gt;&lt;winforms&gt;&lt;type-conversion&gt;&lt;opacity&gt;" AnswerCount="13" CommentCount="1" FavoriteCount="28" CommunityOwnedDate="2012-10-31T16:42:47.213" />
  <row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4" CreationDate="2008-07-31T22:17:57.883" Score="234" Body="&lt;p&gt;An explicit cast to double isn't necessary.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;double trans = (double)trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Identifying the constant as &lt;code&gt;5000.0&lt;/code&gt; (or as &lt;code&gt;5000d&lt;/code&gt;) is sufficient:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;&#xA;double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000d;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="9" LastEditorUserId="967315" LastEditDate="2012-10-14T11:50:16.703" LastActivityDate="2012-10-14T11:50:16.703" CommentCount="0" />
```

Comment: I don't think the error is related to memory allocation. Please post full error message!

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback; you've missed the details of what the error actually is.

Comment: I've posted precisely the full traceback. Please advice on the debug statement to use in order to see more details of the error.

Comment: Maybe relevant or not but look at your `file` parameter. You pass an absolute path without an xml extension but in your defined function, `update_table()` you add the dump path in `with open()`. Try changing parameter to just 'Posts'. Next, I'll advise using the lxml module and xpath your needed nodes/attributes instead of `iterparse()`. See note in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: There should be some error lines *above* the traceback posted, and those are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, consider using xpath in [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library in loop of defined function:

```
import lxml.etree as et  # TO REPLACE: from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse
...

with open(os.path.join(dump_path, file + '.xml'), encoding='utf8') as xml_file:
    table_name = file
    cur = conn.cursor()        
    tree = et.parse(xml_file)

# PULLS EVERY PARENTID ATTRIBUTE IN DOCUMENT REGARDLESS OF LOCATION INTO LIST
parentidval = tree.xpath("//row/@ParentId")  
# PULLS EVERY ID ATTRIBUTE IN DOCUMENT REGARDLESS OF LOCATION INTO LIST
idval = tree.xpath("//row/@Id")

for p, i in zip(parentidval, idval):
    query = update_query.format(parentIdValue=p,idValue=i)
    cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
```

BREAKING LARGE FILE INTO SMALLER PIECES---------------------------

```
for ftimes in range(1,6):  # REMOVE SMALLER FILES IF EXISTS
    fname = os.path.join(dump_path, 'Posts{0}.xml'.format(ftimes))
    if os.path.isfile(fname): 
        os.remove(fname)    

f = open(os.path.join(dump_path, 'Posts.xml'))  # OPENING LARGE FILE

for ftimes in range(1,6):  # NUMBER OF SMALLER FILES (HERE 5) 
    fname = os.path.join(dump_path, 'Posts{0}.xml'.format(ftimes))
    for line, i in zip(f, range(1,101)):   # NUMBER OF LINES PER FILE (HERE 100)
        w = open(fname, 'a', newline='')
        w.write(line)
        w.close()

f.close() 
# PASS EACH POST1.XML, POST2.XML, POST3.XML... IN DEFINED FUNCTION update_table()
```

**XSLT**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="posts">
<posts>
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <row>
        <Id><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></Id>
        <ParentId><xsl:value-of select="@ParentId"/></ParentId>
        </row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</posts>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as ET
...

dom = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'Posts.xml'))
xslt = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'Posts.xsl'))

transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

xmlfile = open(os.path.join(cd, 'Posts_py.xml'),'wb')   # SMALLER FILE TO WORK WITH
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<posts>
  <row>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <ParentId/>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Id>7</Id>
    <ParentId>4</ParentId>
  </row>
</posts>
```

OR (without `pretty print`)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<posts><row><Id>4</Id><ParentId/></row><row><Id>7</Id><ParentId>4</ParentId></row></posts>
```

Comment: I definitely want to try this solution out, but since I'm facing some difficulty with installing lxml, might as well share my skepticism about whether this will work. This line `tree = et.parse(xml_file)` in particular. Doesn't it read the entire file into memory? My file is over 32gb. I found `iterparse(xml_file)` as the workaround to avoid reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Actually you would be right. And `lxml` even has its own `iterparse()` and as mentioned in [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html): *A very important use case for iterparse() is parsing large generated XML files, e.g. database dumps*. Another workaround is to chop up the large xml every 10,000 lines or so and then run script iterations or xpaths multiple times per smaller xml file. Even post a snippet of your XML, I can write an XSLT solution to extract only the nodes you need for database import script!

Comment: I've added a snippet of my xml file to the text of the post question. Yes, it seems that as last resort I'll have to go with chopping the file.

Comment: See my edit of both approaches: 1) breaking files into smaller pieces - challenge here is to break xml so it is still compliant for xml `iterparse()`, so not to break inside a node; and 2) the XSLT approach to extract only the attributes needed per row node. You will need `lxml` for xslt transform.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant workaround. Although my curiosity for why the MemoryError occurred in the first place still remains unsatiated.